# Official list of games with locked savegames

Tags: ps3

On PS3, some savegames are locked, meaning that you cannot backup them and move them to another console. They can only be transfered on a new PS3 system through the online PS+ program facility ($$) or by transferring data from the old system to the new one through provided system tool on the console.

(Problem with latter case is that you have to have both consoles up and running at that time, which is not the case if you buy a new one cause the first one crashed, or if you sell the old one to be able to buy the new one).

I then wanted to know if there is a somewhat official and up-to-date (maintained) list of games fitting this category so that I can know if I'm concerned or not and if my external HDD backup is enough or not in case my console crashes.

I've seen some lists here and there on the web but don't know how accurate they are.

Comment: How much is it worth for you to be sure your saved games are safe? I strongly believe the PSN+ cloud service is well worth the subscription fee.

Comment: @YellowMegaMan that's a good question. From the list below, very few of my games are concerned, so I'm analyzing what to do now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PS3trophies.org Seems to be maintaining a community sourced list, which currently contains over 200 titles, and lists other information that might be of importance.

It can be found [in a topic on their forums](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/general-ps3-discussion/62819-ps3ts-official-locked-saved-games-thread.html)

It believe that this is the most comprehensive list you can get.